# stop event bubbling when focus on table th

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input on my table th, th has a click listener, user want to use the input but the click will trigger, how to stop seperate them? Tried e.preventDefault but no effect.

```
class App extends Component {

  fireSort = () => {
    alert('fireClick')
  }

  fireSearch = () => {

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <th onClick={() => this.fireSort()}>
              My TH
              <input onChange={()=>this.fireSearch()} type="text" placeholder="search" />
            </th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr><td>value</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In the `th` `click` event handler, check what `event.target` is. If it is the `input`, do nothing. `onClick={(evt) => if(evt.target === theInput) { ... }}`

Comment: @codekaizer where?

Comment: @CasaLim use `event.stopPropagation()` to your child elem. say `input`. This will prevent the `click` event from bubbling up to your `th` element

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.stopPropagation to stop the event bubbling